# gsoap and WS-Notification

Tags: c++, wsdl, gsoap, ws-notification

I would like to use WS-Notification in my gsoap client in order to receive notifications from a server. I have developed the wsdl, and every operation, except the notification operations, are built correctly.

I ran a search on the web to find for a solution, and in some places it was stated that gsoap did not currently support the WS-Notification event.

Is this true? Or is my wsdl file not well formed?

Comment: Where did it say that?